# How do I make an outer div with overflow:auto expand to the height of its contents up to a point?

Tags: html, css

I have a div (frame_outer) that contains another div (frame_inner) with dynamic content inside of it. What I want is for frame_outer to expand its height automatically until it either hits the height of frame_inner or its own max-height.

It may be worth mentioning that the reason I have frame_outer in the first place is because sometimes I want frame_inner's content to expand horizontally without blowing out the side of the page (hence `overflow:auto` on frame_outer).

[JSFiddle is here.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8cmyv0c/)

I've tried playing with `clear:both`, `height:auto`, `display:block` in various ways but nothing seems to work.

Fiddle's Code:

HTML:

```
<div class="frame_outer">
    <div class="frame_inner">
        <ul class="my-col">Important stuff</ul>
        <ul class="my-col">Important stuff
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff yay yay cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
            <li class="inside-col">Cool stuff</li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="my-col">Important stuff</ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.frame_outer {
    overflow: auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    max-width: 320px;
    max-height: 640px;
    /* I don't know how to make my stuff appear without manually setting height like below */
    /* height: 1000px; */
    /* What I want is for frame_outer to expand automatically either until it hits the height of frame_inner or its max-height*/
}
.frame_inner {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 150%;
}
.my-col {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: #eeeeee;
    width: 20%;
}
.inside-col {
    background: #ebe7eb;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    border: solid #808080 1px;
    width: 90%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was happening because frame_inner had absolute position to it.

Removing that and just giving width and float property makes it appear inside frame_outer. And also it is horizontal as well as vertically scrollable.

This is the class which I updated,

```css
.frame_inner {
    float:left;
    width: 150%;
}
```

Check the updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/k8cmyv0c/1/)

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: So simple! I'll check to see if it breaks any of my other code and accept your answer if not. If it does, I'll need to update my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Removing `position: absolute;` from `.frame_inner` worked for me

Answer (score -1):

try this....

```
$(".frame_outer").css("height",$(".frame_inner").css("height"));
```

Comment: OP was asking about css / markup solution. Also he is not using a javascript library like JQuery.

Comment: using css it cannot be done until position absolute from frame_inner is not removed

Comment: sure and that its the problem. For that it is no need to add a third party library to deal with the problem. This solution would work, but it will not fit in this specific case (user have not jquery, user can modify the css and html).